# Azure ML deploy locally: tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully

Tags: python, deployment, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to deploy(local) using this line:

```
local_service = Model.deploy(ws, "test", [model], inference_config, deployment_config)
```

Then I get this output in the terminal:

```
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

[Screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXbPe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug with the retry logic when files were being uploaded. That bug has since been fixed, so updating your SDK should fix the issue.

Similar post: [Registering and downloading a fastText .bin model fails with Azure Machine Learning Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854136/registering-and-downloading-a-fasttext-bin-model-fails-with-azure-machine-learn)